# I need a help on copying selected checkbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to copy the checked items from the check box.

I am unable to understand how we can remove the empty list from item list.

**HTML :**

```
<div id="grocery-list">
  <h3>Item List</h3>
  <ul>
    <li class="empty">Empty</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Add Item</legend>
    <label for="item">Item:</label>
    <input id="item" type="checkbox" name="vehicle"  value="bike"/>I have a bike 
    <br>
    <input id="item" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="cycle" />I have a bicycle 
    <br>
    <input id="item" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="aeroplane" />I have a aeroplane 
    <br/>
    <input id="item" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"/>I have a car

    <button>Add</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

**JS :**

```
 $( "button" ).button();

function addToList( value ) {
    var list = $( "#grocery-list ul" );
    list.append( "<li>" + value + "</li>" );
    list.find( ".empty" ).remove();
};

$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $( "input" ).effect( "transfer", {
        to: "#grocery-list ul",
        complete: function() {
            addToList( $( this ).val() );
            $( this ).val( "" ); 
        }
    });
});
```

**[My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/waqasadil/7HQDK/51/)**

Thanks in Advance for your great kind help.

Comment: My Fiddle is :    http://jsfiddle.net/waqasadil/7HQDK/51/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try `$("input:checked")` instead of just `$("input")`

Comment: Zakaria first of all thankyou for my help.and i want to copy the only checked values from the ticked check boxes.

Comment: Rory McCrossan , i have tried $("input:checked") it but it was not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$( "button" ).button();

function A( values ) {
    var items = $( "#grocery-items ul" );
    items.empty();
    values.each(function(){
     items.append( "<li>" + $(this).val() + "</li>" );
    });
};

$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $( "input:checked" ).effect( "transfer", {
        to: "#grocery-items ul",
        complete: function() {
            A( $( "input:checked" ) );
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I edited your fiddle, check it here:

jsfiddle.net/7HQDK/56/